# How far could the "Eye of Sauron" see and what is its resolution?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, sauron

How far and how clear could the "Eye of Sauron" see? Could it see through the whole of Middle-earth or is it limited to only Mordor? Could it distinguish the human face, the small artifacts like rings, or not?

Saruman says the "Eye of Sauron"

> "sees all — his gaze pierces cloud, shadow, earth and flesh. You know of what I speak, Gandalf — a great Eye… lidless… wreathed in flame"

when he is intimidating Gandalf. This implies that Sauron could see everything, just like Superman. If this is true, how could the One Ring escape his gaze? Sauron just needed to scan the land of the Shire. I am afraid that the meeting in Rivendell is also under Sauron's sight. When Frodo brings up the One Ring and Gimli wields his axe, Sauron will see. And once he saw the Ring, he can see it always.

Does this mean that Saruman is exaggerating? What is the true limit of the "Eye of Sauron"?

Comment: This is almost certainly a duplicate, I believe we've had a very similar question asked recently that was itself a duplicate

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [Sauron's sight details?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/58876/31394) (@Edlothiad jinx)

Comment: Yes Saruman is exaggerating. We can gather from the story that Sauron has immense foresight and wisdom given his Maia nature and it stands to be improved further if he takes possession of the One Ring. But he is far from omniscient and his hubris in fact lends some blind spots to his vision.

Comment: It might not have been the wisest choice of Peter Jackson to cast a giant spotlight in the role of Sauron after all...

Comment: I actually like the scene in the 2nd(?) Hobbit movie that "reveals" that the Eye is really just Sauron (the pupil) in a halo of fire (the iris). One of the few design decisions that I don't feel detracted from the rest of the source material.