# Who made the Nazgûl's swords?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, nazgul

In Mordor, who created the swords for the Nazgûl?

As they were kings of men from different places before the became wraiths I'd say that their swords were made by men, but I am not sure.

Comment: https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Ringwraith_sword - "*The Ringwraith sword were long swords of black steel that were hand-forged in Mordor for the Ringwraiths, the deadliest servants of Sauron.*"

Comment: @Valorum where did the wiki got that info?

Comment: Dunno. If they referenced it, I'd have posted it as an answer

Comment: @Valorum why not answer it

Comment: @Ginge - Because "*Someone posted on a random wiki that xyz*" isn't the kind of answer I personally want to be associated with.

Comment: Unlike their daggers, I don't think the swords are mentioned much at all. There's AFAIK nothing saying that the swords would be special or magical in any way.

Comment: I always though swords where from time before wraiths got their rings.

Comment: The only proper answer is imo: Canonically, we do not know and it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 23):

I'm willing to be corrected on this, but I think the answer is "we don't know". The swords could have been made in Mordor, Minas Morgul, Dol Guldur... They might even be artifacts from the Nazgûl's countries of origin.

The only information I can recall about their weapons is that the blade the Witch-king uses to stab Frodo is referred to as a "Morgul-knife" by Gandalf in "Many Meetings". So this was probably made in Minas Morgul, but it wasn't the Witch-king's sword, only a knife that he used with his other hand.

Comment: Morgul is just the Sindarin word for sorcery (with the implication of evil magic) and the term could be just to describe the evil power of the knife, rather than where it was made.

Comment: @suchiuomizu --- it's a capital 'M'.

Comment: Good answer!  All we know about Morgul knives is that they are enchanted. They could be ordinary knives -- plunder from Osgilliath, for all we know -- enchanted by the Nazgul.

Comment: I think we don't know is the most likely, but in the (very not Canon)  Shadow of War PC game...  


***Spoiler Alert***  
You, Talion the ranger, kill one of the Nazgúl and take his ring, eventually replacing him. In the time being you single-handedly hold back the forces of Mordor, explaining why Sauron didn't attack earlier than he does in the LOTR.  


In this case you keep your sword, so maybe they just use the ones they had in life?

Comment: @IanThompson I gave the bounty to your answer, however I didn't accept it, as, imo, "We don't know" is acceptable if it's accompanied by a list of the references that you checked.

Answer (score 3):

#### *Speculation*

## The Necromancer / Sauron

If we presume "Morgul" as the term used to be linked with **[Minas Morgul](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Minas_Morgul)**, which thus implies a domain/stronghold of Sauron, then we can look to early drafts of *The Fellowship of the Ring*:

> Gandalf calls the weapon that was used 'a deadly blade, **the knife of the Necromancer** which remains in the wound', not a 'Morgul-knife'
>
> <sub>*The Return of the Shadow: The History of the Lord of the Rings*, Pt1, Christopher Tolkien - p.211</sub>

In a later draft:

> The 'Morgul-knife' is still the 'knife of the Necromancer'
>
> <sub>*The Return of the Shadow: The History of the Lord of the Rings*, Pt1, Christopher Tolkien - p.363</sub>

Thus - we can see that originally, Tolkien was associating the one named weapon in the text very directly with Sauron. He later changed it of course to 'Morgul-knife' but again, given the association of Minas Morgul and Sauron, it isn't unreasonable to presume then that Sauron or someone quite close to him constructed their weapons.

Comment: Gandalf calls the weapon that was used 'a deadly blade', not a 'Morgul-knife'. >'a deadly blade, the knife of the Necromancer which remains in the wound' - (there's stuff in that block quote that shouldn't be). Also, [Why is Sauron called “the Necromancer”?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47756/why-is-sauron-called-the-necromancer), backs this answer up.

Comment: the stuff in the block quote is verbatim from Christopher Tolkien's book cited in the answer. In it, he's talking about drafts, not the final print edition. Yet, in the final print edition - (at least my copy) Gandalf says "They tried to pierce your heart with a Morgul-knife, which remains in the wound.' Any problems with the block quotes you can take up with the author's kid. He's the one holding all the notebooks :D @Mazura

Answer (score -5):

## The swords were made in Mordor.

According to lotr fandom, the swords were made in Mordor specifically for the Nazgûl.

> The Ringwraith sword were long swords of black steel that were hand-forged in Mordor for the Ringwraiths, the deadliest servants of Sauron.
>
> They wielded these weapons mainly during the War of the Ring until their deaths in March 25, 3019, when Sauron was finally destroyed.

Comment: I've downvoted. This fan-written wiki seems to be making a bold assertion but hasn't offered any evidence to back it up

Comment: The only Ringwraith that was singled wields a Morgul Blade. See Appearance and characteristics section. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazg%C3%BBl

Comment: FWIW, the lotr.fandom page this unreferenced claim was copied from was [deleted in August 2019](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Special:Log?type=delete&page=Ringwraith_sword).