# Does the Necromancer from "The Hobbit" have anything to do with the Dark Lord Sauron?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-hobbit

I finished reading *The Hobbit* around a week or so ago, and given how ominously the Necromancer was mentioned, I was sure he was being set up to be the main villain (or somebody very important to the plot). I've read up to the part where Gandalf's telling a now 50-year-old Frodo about the lore of Bilbo's ring, and he keeps talking about the Dark Lord Sauron.

Do we know what happened to the Necromancer? Additionally, are there any extra books that go into detail about who the Necromancer is and what evil things he did during his time as an evil tyrant?

Comment: @Ishaan Saha  If you are starting to read the Lord of the Rings youcan look forward to enjoying finding out a lot about Middle-earth, and more importantly to a reader, what is going to happen to the characters next.

Comment: See also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/47756/4918 "Why is Sauron called “the Necromancer”?"

Answer (score 9):

The Necromancer is Sauron.  I have to double check if any mention of this is made in the Hobbit but it is certainly confirmed in Lord of the Rings, I want to say both at the Council of Elrond and appendix at least.

Comment: It is never mentioned in the Hobbit, but yes it is confirmed in both the CoE and the appendix.

Comment: I think that the identity of the necromancer and Sauron is mentionedsomewhere in "Shadow of the Past" when Gandalf tells Frodo about Sauron's ring, but I can't remember for certain.